# ARKit Persistence worldMappingStatus Always Limited

Tags: persistence, augmented-reality, arkit

I am developing an ARKit application using World Tracking. However, the worldMappingStatus is always limited. Does anyone have the same issue or know how it can be solved?

Best regards,
Casper

Answer (score 0):

That's not normal but I'd need a bit more info to properly answer your question. 1- How do you know it's always limited? 2- are you moving the phone around when you launch the app to "understand the surroundings" 3- what code have you tried?